# How to modify "null" to "not null" in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I need to change from "null" to "not null".

I have a table with following structure:

```
Created_By   Created_Date_Time   Modified_By    Modified_Date_Time
NULL            NULL                -1                 NULL
NULL            NULL                -1                 NULL
NULL            NULL                -1                 NULL
```

I need to change `Modified_By` from `-1` to `null`.

I am trying with the following query but it gives me an error:

```
update BOM_Rules
set Modified_By = not null
```

Error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Modified_By', table 'dbo.BOM_Rules'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

I am sure I am missing something important. Maybe `alter table`?

```
ALTER TABLE BOM_Rules
ALTER COLUMN Modified_By NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

I am using SQL2008R2.

Comment: There is no `NOT NULL` value. That term is only used in DDL and `WHERE` clauses. You have to actually set a value if you want something to be *not null*

Comment: `set Modified_By = not null` ought to give you the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'not'`. as that is not valid syntax`. Not an error about inserting `NULL`

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. You say that you need to change 'from "null" to "not null"', but then you say that the `Modified_By` field contains `-1`, and that you want to change it to null. So, which is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the Modified_By column does not allow nulls.  Try altering the column to allow nulls:

```
ALTER TABLE BOM_Rules
ALTER COLUMN Modified_By NVARCHAR(50) NULL
```

Comment: This interpretation of the question makes the most sense to me. I presume they must have been running `update BOM_Rules set Modified_By = null` rather than the query they say in the question.